# Why does AJAX GET response from PHP have HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

My response text has html tags which causes ERROR  to fire instead of SUCCESS. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my html code:

```
<head>
    <title>HTML Window</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function post() {
            var email = document.getElementById("email");
            var password = document.getElementById("password");
            var data = {
                email: email.value,
                password: password.value
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost/ParentChild/index.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: data,
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log("SUCCESS");
                    console.log(response);
                },
                error: function (response, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log("ERROR");
                    console.log("Status: " + textStatus);
                    console.log(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="GET" action="javascript:post();">
        <div>
            Parent Window
            <br><label for="email">Email: <input type="text" id="email" name="email"></label>
            <br><label for="password">Password: <input type="text" id="password" name="password"></label>
            <br><input type="submit" value="Post">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Here's my php:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $response = array(
        "a" => "test");
    echo (json_encode($response);
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the console message:

```
ERROR
(index):28 Status: parsererror
(index):29 errorThrown: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
(index):30 <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {"a":"test"}    </body>
```

If I remove dataType: "json", I SUCCESS fires but the html tags are still part of the response text.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's because your php snippet embeds the results within an html page.

Comment: Because you have them in your php....

Comment: just let your other php file contain a header content json and the echo json encode response

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP script that return data to the ajax call should be treated pretty much like a subroutine and not a web page. If you have HTML in that script, it will also be sent back to the browser as part of the total response.

So amend the script to this i.e. remove all the HTML you had in it

```
<?php
$response = array("a" => "test");
echo (json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks all...now I understand!